# How can i read html codes with python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to get a link in html path, the codes are here:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> 
      <a href="https://storage.googleapis.com/audiog-204018.appspot.com/files/hello1574358335.mp3"> 
      Download MP3 </a>
</div>
```

How can i get this link with selenium

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  In this case, you should post the selenium code that you wrote to address your issue to demonstrate you've made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Python Selenium you can simply use element.get_attribute()**

So in your case, it should just be

```
element.get_attribute("href")
```